# Getting hiddenvalue HTML property from javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to access the hidden HTML value (hiddenvalue) from javascript and storing it into a variable env.

HTML:

```
<button id="slct" hiddenfield="Forest" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Hello</button>
```

JS:

```
$('#slct').click(function (event) {
document.getElementById('env').value = $('#' + $(event.target).data('hiddenfield')).value;
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Try `var env = $("#slct").attr("hiddenfield")`

Comment: Do you have an html element with the 'env' id that you're planning on storing this in? Because if you wanted to put it in a Javascript variable it should be `var env = `

Comment: jquery does not have .value

Comment: There's an attribute called `hiddenfield`? is that HTML6 improved version of `type="hidden"`?. o_0

Comment: @XByte please stop using `hiddenfield` as an attribute, there' no such thing. And if you have a value on a button, that does not make it hidden, unless that button is visibly obscured. You should use it like this: `data-hiddenfield`.

Comment: Yep that was it - small oversight from my end. Thanks

Comment: @X'Byte as epascarello said earlier there is no `.value` property in jQuery. `$('#' + $(event.target).data('hiddenfield')).value;` should probably be `$('#'+event.target).data('hiddenfield').val();` Be careful with using standard JS objects in the same expression as a jQuery object, they are not the same, you'll get a type error most likely.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a hidden html field

```
<input type="hidden" id="someId" value="someValue">
```

Getting the value of this field would look like:

```
var theValue = document.getElementById('someId').value;
```

What you want is probably this:
html:

```
<input type="hidden" id="env" value="">
<button class="slct" hiddenfield="Forest" type="button" class="btn btn-default">This sets Forest</button>
<button class="slct" hiddenfield="Fruit" type="button" class="btn btn-default">This sets Fruit</button>
```

javascript:

```
$('.slct').click(function(event) {
    // Set value to hidden field
    $('#env').val($(this).attr('hiddenfield'));
});
```

you can use `data()` instead of `attr()`, but the attribute needs to start with 'data-' then. E.g. `data('hiddenvalue')` to retrieve the value of attribute `data-hiddenvalue`
(see https://jsfiddle.net/2k0791hk/1/)

Comment: 'env' is another hidden html field (saves to db). What you suggested crossed my mind, however I have several buttons and this would be quite chunky..

Comment: I wanted to write one script to cater for all buttons